# JackAudio disabled in Blender's OSX official release?

Tags: audio, osx

I need to use JACK as Blender's audio device, mostly to sync with Ardour via Jack Transport. I've done this in linux but in OSx (10.13) Jack doesn't show in the audio devices list.

bpy.app.build_options.Jack in the python console drops False. I guess the build option comes disabled by default. Is that because Blender is no longer compatible with Jack in OSx? Is there any build with the option activated?

Any guidance will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Blender installer detects missing files related to Jack. I realised this building Blender from the source code. I had to correct the file location of Jack .h files, then it compiled correctly and Jack fully works. This is an issue affecting MacOSX 10.13 + JackOSx 0.92_3. Probably due the fact that Jack is not yet fully supported in newer OSX versions.